# How do I revoke access to a file remotely after it was downloaded by a website user

Tags: remote-access, file-security, remote-management

DRM services, data rooms and document storage services market themselves with the ability to "remote shred" or "remote wipe" a file or access to a file after it has been downloaded to a local machine, without the use of additional local software.

Adobe DRM has content management services, but looks to require software on the local machine.

You could set expiration date on a PDF, but what are some ways you could set a PDF or say an excel spreadsheet to be inaccessible or corrupted at any point in the future. Accept that the file could be cloned and that the local machine disconnected from the internet.

Have set expiration dates on a PDF and added password protect, but the expiration date must be arbitrary at download, as opposed to being able to revoke access at a certain point.

What's the best strategy for protecting a file from future access if it is allowed to be downloaded? Really interested in this type of technology. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the only way to do this is; the "file" the user downloads in fact contacts the cloud, ie, every single time the user wants to read the file.